# Selecting all checked checkbox return all checkbox instead using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here is my code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nw93nzx/3/)

`JS file`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".test").children().filter(function(index, elem){
      console.log($(elem).children(":checked"));
    });

})
```

`HTML`

```
 <ul class="test">
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="1"><label>something</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="2"><label>something</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="3"><label>something</label></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="4" checked><label>something</label></li>
 </ul>
```

I am trying to select all checked checkbox, but if I filtered by `:checked` I get all checkbox instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

To be more precise

```
var allChecked = $('.test input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

get you all checked checkboxes under as child of element having class `test` and to test if checkbox is checked you can use

```
var bool = $(selector).is(":checked"); 
// return true if checked false if not
//where selector can be any jQuery selector
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the checked inputs you simply need to use:

`var checked = $("input:checked");`

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nw93nzx/4/)

If it must be limited to inputs within that `ul` only, you can specify the class as well:

`var checked = $(".test input:checked");`

See this [fiddle to select all checked inputs in a given ul](https://jsfiddle.net/6nw93nzx/7/).

Comment: I have other checkbox not under `class="test"`

Comment: `$(".test input:checked")` will return null

Comment: I'm not sure what result you are seeing. Please see the extra link I have posted - it returns the checked inputs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers suggest better ways to select the checked checkbox you want, and I agree that those are more straight-forward methods and are preferable to your filtering approach, but here I try to explain what you're actually seeing in your code as you have it.

Going to your fiddle and running it in the Chrome debugger, it looks like it's doing the right thing, and you simply may not be seeing what you expect due to the behavior of `console.log()`

I split your console.log line to take two separate steps — get the child(ren) that match the `:checked` selector, then log that variable; so it looks like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".test").children().filter(function(index, elem) {
        //console.log($(elem).children(":checked"));
        boxen = $(elem).children(":checked");
        debugger;
        console.log(boxen);
    });
})
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nw93nzx/8/)

This loops making the call to the filter() function four times — one for each of the originally selected `$(".test").children()` elements.  On the first call, index will be `0` (zero) and elem will be the first `<li>` element.
Calling `boxen = $(elem).children(":checked");` will give you `[]` ... that is, an empty array, since none of the children of that first *li* are checked.
However, when you `console.log(boxen)` it gives you some *"weird"* output because this is jQuery... it's not a plain javascript array.

When you get to the fourth iteration, looking at the fourth selected element, index will be `3` and elem will be that fourth `<li>`
When you `$(elem).children(":checked")` on *that* one, you'll get something like `[<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"4" checked>​]` (how you see it will depend some on your javascript debugger) — so this time it ***is*** selecting the one checked input element.

If you select `.children(":checked")` into a variable you are indeed getting the one checkbox you want, but the `console.log()` output is deceiving you.